# Run a psql query from a shell script

Tags: shell, psql

I have a PSQL statement which needs to be run from a shell script.
I have tried below but no success

`ctfdb` is my database

```
psql ctfdb <<EOF
statement
EOF
```

> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "root"

I have even tried giving "sudo psql"

> Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/bin/psql ctfdb' as root
>   on my server

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql -U postgres ctfdb`

Connects as user `postgres`. You are connecting to the DB as your shell username `root`.

There are other ways such as setting the `PGUSER` environment variable or configuring `pg_hba.conf` to allow access for other users.